# Objects and floor being cut off when zoomed in

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I've seen tutorials on this site from the old lay out, but even after editing the "Clip Start" setting, when I'm in the 3D Viewport, it still clips.[image: Still clipping]

Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: To what value have you set your 'clip start' setting?

Answer (score 1):

You are editing your scene camera's clip settings, when you really need to be editing your view's clip settings.

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the side menus, go the the "View" tab, and you should find the relevant options.

[image: Clip start and end in the toolshelf menus]